# How to setup serialization in IntelliJ/Kotlin?

Tags: gradle, kotlin, intellij-idea

My apologies for a noob question: I'm trying to check out how serialization works in Kotlin.

To this end, I created a Gradle project like this:

[image]

edited the generated `build.gradle.kts`by adding just one line

```
plugins {
    java
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.71"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization") version "1.3.71"
}

group = "org.example"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
    testCompile("junit", "junit", "4.12")
}

configure<JavaPluginConvention> {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
tasks {
    compileKotlin {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    compileTestKotlin {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

and created this Kotlin source file:

```
import kotlinx.serialization.*
import kotlinx.serialization.json.*

@Serializable
data class Data(val a: Int, val b: String = "42")
```

But when I build this project, I get this error:

```
Unresolved reference: kotlinx
```

If I remove the first two offending lines, I get this error instead:

```
Cannot access 'Serializable': it is internal in 'kotlin.io'
```

What am I doing wrong here? (Also, do I need Gradle to use serialization in IntelliJ/Kotlin 1.3.71? )

Comment: surprised to see no answers from someone else in 6 months. Thanks , your answer worked for me.

Comment: Looks like they corrected it now at https://kotlinlang.org/docs/serialization.html#example-json-serialization

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally, figured it out. A **BUG** in IntelliJ IDEA was foiling my troubleshooting.

Leaving the answer for anyone who might find this question via Google:

`build.gradle.kt` needs to be

```
plugins {
    java
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.71"
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.3.71"
}

repositories {
    // artifacts are published to JCenter
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib", org.jetbrains.kotlin.config.KotlinCompilerVersion.VERSION))
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime:0.20.0")
}
```

The official instructions have a buggy version of this: no `org.jetbrains.kotlin.config.`

However, this is not enough. I was executing "Run" from the Kotlin file. This leads to another error

```
error: unable to evaluate script, no scripting plugin loaded
```

due to a nasty bug (as in, I wasted **HOURS** and **HOURS** trying to figure out what I was doing wrong) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-37814

One needs to *explicitly* execute "Build project".

Comment: In case this doesn't work, here's what worked for me. Remove the `kotlin("plugin.serialization") version` from the applied plugins. Build project, re-add it and build project again. I assume it's just an IntelliJ bug.