# IntelliJ IDEA keeps highlighting "serialization" as an error

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

IntelliJ IDEA keeps highlighting  "serialization" as an error, even though this builds fine ([after much trial-and-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60940476/how-to-use-serialization-in-intellij-kotlin) due to bugs in the IDE and buggy instructions)

[image]

Is there any way to fix this, or do I have to learn to ignore this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> and you should have an option to add it to project level dictionary and ignore it

[image]

Comment: I'm not seeing this option. IDEA 2020.1 BETA.

Comment: I downgraded to "stable", and the problem went away.